# Colour change buttons not work

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src"change.js"></script>
    <form>
    <input type="button" name="Button1" value="RED" onclick="changecolor('red')">
    <input type="button" name="Button1" value="BLUE" onclick="changecolor('blue')">
    <input type="button" name="Button1" value="Green" onclick="changecolor('green')">
    <input type="button" name="Button1" value="Yellow" onclick="changecolor('yellow')">
    </form>
```

> This code is saved as change.js

```
function changecolor(code) {
    document.bgColor=code
}
```

The colour change buttons appear but does not work.

Comment: script src="" instead of src""

Comment: `document.bgColor`is deprecated. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/document.bgColor)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f4pb1mvs/ Your code works

Comment: Try to change `document.bgColor` by `document.body.style.backgroundColor`

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

`src"change.js"` is missing an = sign. Should be `src="change.js"`